# Change Xcode auto-formatting of NSDictionary

Tags: xcode, nsdictionary, autoformatting

I'm trying to change Xcode's auto-formatting of the `NSDictionary` to conform to a style guide:

Xcode behavior:

```
NSDictionary *resourceResponseDictionary = @{
                                             @"status": @"OK",
                                             @"result": [NSDictionary dictionary]
                                             };
```

Desired behavior:

```
NSDictionary *resourceResponseDictionary = @{
    @"status": @"OK",
    @"result": [NSDictionary dictionary]
};
```

Where would I begin to look to make the change? Is it even possible?

Comment: I was looking for a solution for this for ages! I finally "solved" it by disabling `Automatically indent based on syntax`.

Comment: Thanks lulian, found this option in Settings -> Text -> Indentation.

Answer (score 0):

By auto-formatting I guess you mean 'Indentation'. I had a similar question/problem and came to realize that Xcode does not have a specific setting for this except the basic ones in preferences. For example, when adding multiple `<Delegates, DataSource...>`, starting a new line has no indentation formatting at all, and it must be done manually.

Short answer, you can't (without some hack), but, the default is consistent in this case, meaning: Xcode *does* indent, the way it knows how to. IMHO, it won't be a bad idea to adapt it.